Why do Gmail IMAP servers seem out of sync with webmail servers?
I use both webmail and Outlook desktop client to access my Gmail. I am normally looking at the All Mail folder on Outlook.  Whenever I drag messages from the All Mail folder to the Trash folder on Outlook, these messages remain visible in the All Mail folder when accessed via webmail.  Furthermore, when calendar invites are accepted using the Outlook client, they disappear from All Mail and go into the Trash folder, but when using WebMail, they remain in the Inbox. I have seen this disparity for years across different Outlook client versions and Windows versions. I also posted on the Gmail subreddit about a year ago.
Do others see this?  How can this be corrected?
I am aware of the difference between Gmail's labels vs. Outlook's folders, but I would expect that Gmail does what is necessary to make the folders appear correct over the IMAP connection to Outlook. For example, if I drag a message from Outlook's All Mail folder to Trash, I see that message disappear from the Inbox folder after a short delay. Hence, the trashing of messages is registering on Gmail. It's just that the contents seem completely disconnected from what I see using webmail. All messages that were trashed in Outlook still appear in All Mail when accessed using webmail, even days later.
This appears to be a sync problem between Google's IMAP servers and Gmail's webmail rather than the Outlook desktop app.
I access the IMAP servers from 3 different machines, and they all see the changes from each other.  The problem is that the some changes are not reflected in the Gmail web app. The disparities aren't temporary. They seem to be permanent. By web app, I mean webmail accessed via Firefox or Chrome for (say) Windows 10, not smartphone app.

It would be helpful if you included your  IMAP settings from Gmail and your Gmail settings in Outlook. Otherwise, it's a guessing game, and my guess would be that Outlook, the IMAP servers, and Gmail are all working properly, doing exactly what they've been instructed to do by their settings. Of particular interest should be how "deletion" is handled/synchronized and how and when (if?) Outlook purges Gmail messages from the IMAP server.

These are the settings to provide from Gmail (image). In Outlook it's the "Purge items when switching folders while online" option status to share with us.

Which version of Outlook, out of curiosity? All of the recent ones (I think 2016+) definitely have a very different way of syncing than traditional IMAP clients...

Is Outlook connected via Imap too?

Please try the following steps:

IMAP Settings: Ensure that your IMAP settings are correctly configured. Go to Gmail settings, click on the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab, and make sure IMAP is enabled. Save the changes and reconfigure your email client with the correct IMAP server settings.
Account Settings: Remove your Google Account from your email client and then try adding it again. This can sometimes resolve sync issues.
Update IMAP Settings: Update your IMAP settings so you don't sync certain folders. This can help reduce the load on the IMAP server and improve sync performance.

In addition, i find a similar thread, it mentioned some methods that you may feel free to refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1819947/when-an-event-created-from-gmail-webmail-exchange

The IMAP settings are made according to Gmail's webpages.  I have created IMAP accounts to Gmail on Outlook countless times through the  years, and always see this problem, across different Windows versions and Outlook versions.  Having to recreate Outlook IMAP accounts is do-able occassionally, but not sustainable on an ongoing basis.  As for not syncing some folders, I only subscribe to the bare minimum of folders (Inbox, All Mail, Sent, and Trash).  I appreciate that you shared your ideas.

I have yet to follow up on Blindspot's suggestion to go through the Gmail account settings for IMAP access (on Gmail, not on Outlook).  Unfortunately, I'm always juggling competing non-work priorities during the weekend, but I still have it as a to-do.

Given your experience and the steps you’ve already taken, it might be worth prioritizing a thorough review of your Gmail account settings for IMAP access when you get a chance. Sometimes, even small adjustments can make a big difference.

I have my desktop app using POP, laptop using webmail and mobile using an imap client. Despite configuring all the settings available, things still go wrong. And I am not moving emails between folder, just reading them. I think that its the Gmail software itself.
I would suggest that frequent changes to folder contents on multiple devices will make it go wrong.

My suggestion is to not use webmail. But install an IMAP client on that device.
If that doesn't work then grab all the mail using POP onto your desktop and let the other devices imap into your desktop.


Thanks, but I need nomadic access to the account from various networks, so I need IMAP.  Outlook is an IMAP device (or rather, IMAP accounts can be configured).  I hardly shuffle any messages between folders other than to drag message to the Trash folder.  That is supposed to cause Gmail to remove tags that cause the message to appear in other folders.  I think that you're right about this being a bug between the main Gmail hosting platform and the IMAP servers.  I was hoping that there was a work-around.  Thanks for sharing your experience.

When you are accessing Gmail via the web application everything is hosted on Google's cloud servers.
When you synchronize mail using IMAP between Gmail and a desktop mail client such as Outlook, there is a necessary delay between changes made independently at both ends being synchronized in both directions.
Simply making a change in Outlook does not in and of itself mean that anything has changed in Gmail.  For example, you can disconnect from the Internet and make changes.  Outlook needs to explicitly reach out to Gmail and communicate the changes you've made.
You should look at your Outlook desktop client settings to review the default synchronization schedule and tweak anything you can to get it to poll Google's IMAP servers more frequently.
There are various variables at play here however, generally speaking, Outlook performs best when operating as a front end for Microsoft Exchange and Gmail when accessed via a web browser.

Thanks, but Outlook client shows sync progress bars for subscribed folders.  The minimum sync frequency is 30 minutes when connected, and I always keep connected, sometimes manually initiating a sync.  The disparity in messages don't fade with time.  They seem to be permanent.  I'll try to screen capture relevant settings for attachment to the posted question.  I strongly suspect that it is not a desktop app setting that is causing this.

The settings that I could find pertain to server names, ports, and encryption. I didn't see any parameters governing sync frequency. However, as I said, I can initiate and monitor syncing of subscribed folders, so I suspect that the problem is not sync frequency. It's not as if the discrepancies eventually resolve themselves. It is the webmail that fails to sync with the IMAP servers, which is why I posted in the Web Apps stack exhange.  Can you be more specific about Outlook parameters that you suspect?  I've researched this many times over the years -- I wonder if I've seen it all.

I should add that I access the Gmail IMAP servers from 3 machines.  All 3 see the same updates from each other.  To me, this seems to clearly show that here is no sync issue between the IMAP servers and Outlook app on the desktop.  The issue is between the IMAP servers and Gmail's webmail.  This is why I didn't post the question to SuperUser, and why I still believe that it belongs on the Web App stack exchange. I tried to post a comment to that effect, and to edit the question to explain this, but neither is possible for the locked thread.

As I said, I could not edit the question (on the web app stack exchange).  I also described a compelling reason for why the problem is not between the Outlook app and the IMAP servers.  I'd be happy to post details, but I also described what details I had access to on my computer and they seemed to be irrelevant.  I asked above what details would be relevant, but given my last comment, they would need to be relevant to the discrepancy between the IMAP servers and Gmail's webmail, not the Outlook app.

OK, I've updated the question with what seem to me to be relevant details.  If other details are deemed relevant, hopefully someone can say what they are so that I can try to obtain them.

Start with the basics: your settings in Outlook and Gmail.

The work week has started.  I will try to respond, but there is a good chance that it will be the weekend when I can.
